# Why does gvim start every new line with TAB?

Tags: vim

I'm using gvim under Windows (version 7.3.46)

Everytime when I press `o` to start a new line, gvim starts the line with a TAB character.

When I set `:se expandtab` the TAB is changed into 8 spaces.

I tried everything to disable the starting TAB without success:

```
set noautoindent
set nosmartindent
set nocindent
```

I'm also using vim under Linux and didn't have such a problem.

THX

Comment: Do you have filetype indentation turned on? Is 'indentexpr' empty?

Comment: Perhaps look into `softtabstop` and `shiftwidth` option. For me I use `set softtabstop=4` `set shiftwidth=4`

Comment: I finally reinstalled `vim` to the latest version and now I don't have problem with it, thank you though